# Find a record in column A and B if match return with count column C

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

Would you mind assisting me by generating a summary derived from the matching of columns A and B in the table below? If column A and B is not match return 0.
Exsample:
Column A: Teddy
Column B: DP
Total is 5

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Teddy | SP | 4 |
| Teddy | DP | 1.5 |
| Peach | O | 2.5 |
| Jack | SP | 1 |
| Jack | O | 1 |
| Peach | O | 1 |
| Teddy | DP | 3.5 |

=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10"Teddy")*($B$2:$B$10="SP"))

Comment: After adding the missing equal sign, simply multiply with the values in column `C`: `=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C10*(A2:A10="Teddy")*(B2:B10="SP"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FILTER()` then `SUM()`.

```
=SUM(FILTER(C2:C,A2:A="Teddy",B2:B="DP"))
```

Or `QUERY()` function.

```
=QUERY(A2:C,"select sum(C) where A='Teddy' and B='DP'",0)
```

[image]